Trying to create auto-resizing horizontally-scrollable background image
I'm trying to recreate this webpage, and I'm looking for advice on my approach.
What I'm trying to achieve:

A background image with a height that always matches the screen height while preserving its aspect ratio.

Additionally, I want the image to be horizontally scrollable when it's wider than the device screen.

Clickable hotspots that remain fixed on particular positions on the background image, regardless of screen size.


Here's my current setup: CodeSandBox
export const Bedroom = ({ blurDataURL, hotspots }: BedroomProps) => {
  return (
    <section id="bedroom">
      <div className="h-screen w-auto relative ">
        {/* I aim to resize this image so that its height matches the screen height while preserving its aspect ratio. Additionally, I want the image to be horizontally scrollable when it's wider than the device screen. Ideally, I would also remove the object-cover property as it woulld affect the hotspots' positioning.  My tech stack includes Next.js, Tailwind CSS, and Typescript. */}
        <Image
          src={src}
          alt={title}
          placeholder="blur"
          blurDataURL={blurDataURL}
          width={4000}
          height={2500}
          className={cn("h-full w-full object-cover")}
        />
        {hotspots.map((hotspot, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className="absolute"
            style={{
              left: hotspot?.position?.left,
              top: hotspot?.position?.top,
              transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
            }}
          >
            <Popover>
              <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                <div className="relative size-10 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
                  <div className="bg-white rounded-full p-3 animate-slow-ping opacity-65" />
                  <div className="bg-white rounded-full p-1 animate-none shadow absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 z-2" />
                </div>
              </PopoverTrigger>
              <PopoverContent
                className={cn(
                  GeistSans.className,
                  "rounded-full capitalize text-sm lg:text-base font-medium tracking-tight px-4 py-1.5"
                )}
              >
                <a href={hotspot?.href}>
                  <div>{hotspot?.name}</div>
                </a>
              </PopoverContent>
            </Popover>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};


After a LOT of debugging, I discovered that the Lenis instance I initialized was the culprit preventing me from horizontally scrolling.
I didn't notice this earlier because this particular page on my app is meant to be 100svh, and the other pages did not need horizontal scrolling.
After implementing a route check for the instance, I was able to come up with this, largely inspired by the original webpage:

<section id='bedroom'>
      <div
        className='relative overflow-x-auto overflow-y-hidden' 
      >
        <div className='relative h-[100svh] aspect-[16/10] lg:w-full'>
          <picture className='h-[100svh] aspect-[16/10] lg:object-cover object-center'>
            <source media='(min-width: 1024px)' srcSet={`${src}?w=4000`} />
            <source media='(min-height: 600px)' srcSet={`${src}?w=2560`} />
            <source media='(min-height: 500px)' srcSet={`${src}?w=1920`} />
            <Image
              src={`${src}?w=1024`}
              alt={title}
              placeholder='blur'
              blurDataURL={blurDataURL}
              width={4000}
              height={2500}
              className='h-[100svh] aspect-[16/10] lg:object-cover'
              priority
            />
          </picture>
          <div className='absolute inset-0'>
            {hotspots.map((hotspot, index) => (
              <BedroomHotspot
                hotspot={hotspot}
                key={index}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

